# High end tcp server 1k connections, with saving data to database

Tags: database, tcp, gprs

We are developing a TCp Server of 1k connections, with async calls it is working fine.
But we have to save the data of each client in DB separately.

How to manage this much large pool of DB connections ideally what should be hardware required?
Can we use a single core machine for TCP Server 1k connection?

INFO: We are having GPRS enabled tcp clients(These are hardware devices which connect to tcp server every 1 min and sends data. **Current Db MYSQL**

Comment: What language are you programming in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would implement it as follows:

1. Have a collection of data that is waiting to be saved protected by a lock.
2. When a thread has new data to be saved, acquire the lock on the collection, add the data to the collection, and release the lock.
3. Have a "save thread" (or save job, or whatever is appropriate for your language or threading library) that periodically acquires the lock on the collection, swaps the collection for an empty collection, releases the lock, and then saves all the data in the collection in a single SQL transaction.

Comment: we are programming in C#, backend MySql,
If i put a lock, will what will be effect on the performance considering we are using Amazon ec2 Small instance 1.7GB RAm gHZ, single core

Comment: The lock is only held when already processed data is added to the collection and when the collection is swapped for an empty collection. If you implement it as I described above, there should be very little contention.

Comment: Ok David I will try this and post you the results.

Comment: Sorry. If you can ask a more specific question, I can try to clarify. The idea is to aggregate the work into chunks and do each chunk as a single SQL transaction. Otherwise, you're limited to one database write per two disk rotations.

Comment: I couldnt understand how this question is unrealistic or vague, as a programmer point of view, I got brilliant answer from david as well. It s all about facing the requirement in real time situation such that the requirement can be grassped.

Comment: Oh! That's what you meant. Thank you.

Comment: The above comment is not for you David, it for those who down voted it